# validate an non-Input model in MVC core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I have an action-method that have an `object type` Input like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomeThing([FromBody]object input, bool options)

{
    if (options == true)
    {
        var castedInput = (A) input;
        if (TryValidateModel(castedInput))
        {
            // do some thing
        }
        else
        {
            //return validation Errors;
            //forexample:return Error("Error1")
            //??!??!!??!?!?!?!??!
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var castedInput = (B)input;
        if (TryValidateModel(castedInput))
        {
            // do some thing
        }
        else
        {
            //return validation Errors;
            //forexample:return Error("You must fill this parameter")
            //??!??!!??!?!?!?!??!

        }
    }
}
```

In this method first I cast Input to my ViewModel then validate it. now I want to return my Validation Errors that I set on annotations of my model.
How can I do this?

My Viewmodels:

```
public class A
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error1")]
    string Phone;
    .
    .
    .
}

public class B
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must fill this parameter")]
    string Name;
    .
    .
    .  
}
```

Comment: It's a really bad idea to not know what shape your inputs should be.  You should have a different, defined, model for each method.

Comment: When you use `[FromBody]object input`,and in debug `var castedInput = (A) input;`,you will get an error like `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' to type 'xxx.A'.`So you need to define the Object to A or B in your action.For example:`public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomeThing1([FromBody]A input)`,`public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomeThing2([FromBody]B input)`

Comment: Thanks for Answers,I am aware of the problems with this method, but in general I want to get validation Error message of a model that is not input. For example, `castedInput` model error messages Do not have an opinion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo worked:

Action:

```
public JsonResult DoSomeThing([FromBody]object input,bool options)

        {
            var model = new Object();
            if (options)
            {
                model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(input.ToString());
            }
            else {
                model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(input.ToString());
            }
            string messages = "";
            if (!TryValidateModel(model))
            {
                messages = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                                 .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                 .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ErrorMessage) ? x.ErrorMessage : x.Exception.Message.ToString()));
            }
            return Json(messages);
        }
```

Models:

```
public class A
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error1")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must fill this parameter")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
     
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Validation errors of `DataAnnotation` can be returned with `ModelState` object.

- A generic function can be used and call it in every `Action`

```
protected string ValidateModel1()
{
    string messages = "";
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        messages = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                         .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                         .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ErrorMessage) ? x.ErrorMessage : x.Exception.Message.ToSubString()));
    }
    return messages;
}
```

- Use this method in controller as:

```
string modelState = ValidateModel();
```

**2nd Way**

Create an `Action Filter` and use it in `Action Attribute` or in Controller level:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string messages = string.Join("; ", actionContext.ModelState.Values
                                                .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                                .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ErrorMessage) ? x.ErrorMessage : x.Exception.Message.ToSubString()));

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, messages);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, how to get messages of a non-Input method? please give an Example or tell me more.

Comment: What do you mean Non-input? You want if there is not any model in Action method parameter?

Comment: Yes similar to `castedInput `.

Comment: Think we a have a model that we want to validate it, and this model dose not member of my Action Input parameters