# How to use dynamic to normal model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to convert dynamic incoming data to normal model and use it. How can I do?
[Click problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7s1s.png)

I get an error on the **ConvertedModel** conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Your `model` variable isn't a JSON string so you can't deserialise it. It's a `dynamic` object - it's a type in C#. If the data has the same structure as your model you could just cast it to that type.

But this shouldn't be necessary anyway - why not just use the model type in the method signature directly? It's unclear why you have set it up this way.

If you write it like this then ASP.NET will automatically attempt to deserialise the incoming data directly to your model type:

```
public AjaxResponse AddFavourite(YourModelClass model) {
```

Comment: actually my goal is to learn something new and try to find another easy way

Comment: Ok. But...why? This isn't a useful thing to learn. The way I've shown is already the easiest way. I suggest learning something that will actually improve your code, instead.

Comment: To focus on my code through a single model rather than writing multiple models. I have too many methods on hand and I will need to do this on all of them. That's why I looked for something like this.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. Having a separate model for each action method is usually a _good_ thing, because then you only have the exact fields you need in each situation. Sometimes you might find a model can be shared between a few actions (e.g. one action to get some data, and another to update the same data), but mostly not. And that's fine. Besides, your idea isn't going to save you any time because you would still have to go into all the methods and write code to cast them all to the type you really want.

Comment: You're just over-complicating it for no reason. Like I said, learn something useful and let the .NET framework get on with dealing with deserialising the data, as it's designed to do. The whole point of putting the model type into the method signature is to save you the trouble of deserialising or casting it yourself. You seem to want to re-invent the wheel. It _won't_ help you, it _won't_ save you time, and it _will_ cause you extra work and extra problems, as you've already discovered. Don't fight the system, it's there to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a dynamic data to a normal model,it is possible,but you need to pass data to tell which model you want to convert.You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401761/validate-an-non-input-model-in-mvc-core/63502400#63502400):
Here is a demo worked:

```
 public class A { 
     public string userid { get; set; }
     public string symbol { get; set; }
    }
    public class B
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class C
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult DynamicModel([FromBody]dynamic d,string modelName) {
            var model = new Object();
            switch (modelName)
            {
                case "A":
                    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(d.ToString());
                    break;
                case "B":
                    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(d.ToString());
                    break;
                case "C":
                    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C>(d.ToString());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return Ok(model);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can use
string strJSON = JsonConvert.SerilzeObject();
var model = JsonConvert.Deserialize(strJSON);

Comment: How is this relevant in any way? I think you haven't properly understood the question.